# Is there an open source java message flow designer or similar tool?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, message

I am looking for an opensource product or some code examples of how I might design either a Java or HTML based GUI to design message flows.

One would add nodes/entities to the diagram and then messages that would flow between entities. The properties of the nodes and entities could then be modified.

The reason I want to extend something open source or code it from scrath is that I have numerous formats that i want to export the data in such as :

1. An image of the flow for use in documentation.
2. Human readable description of the message flow.
3. A test script to simulate the flow.

In an ideal world this would eventually be an Eclispe plug-in which is why I'd like it to be done using a sutable Java GUI framework however if a tool exists that could export message flows in a good structured langauge (XML) I guess my tool could just import this and convert to the other formats required.

Any ideas?

Comment: After doing some deeper research I think the Eclipse GMF may be a good fraework on which to build the tool. Anyone have any experince with it that can point out some good resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse GMF is a good choice, but it is quite hard once you start putting in advanced features.

Take a look at the [jboss jpdl designer](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v3/gpd/). I think it is built on top of an extensible core library for graph modeling. I know for a fact that jBPM is built like that, so this one also might be built along the same lines. If it is so, you should be able to reuse the core library.

Comment: We use Eclipse for our dev so the GMF is likely to be the one we use. But yours is the only answer so thanks for the help anyway.